# How to write an Excel function which returns a value from an ACCESS database?

Tags: database, vba, excel, ms-access

I have a database in access 2013

Date   | Data

01/06/2015 | 1

02/06/2015 | 2

And I want to write a function that returns values from DB.

```
=GETDATA("FORDATE")
```

Is this possible  ?
I have tried this but it doesn't want to work

```
Public Function GetData(id As Date) As String

Set oConnection = New ADODB.Connection
Dim oRecordset As ADOR.Recordset

oConnection.Open "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\user\Desktop\CAINV_DB.accdb;" & "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
Set oRecordset = oConnection.Execute("select " & RDATE & " from CB_EXCHANGE where RDATE = " & id)
If oRecordset.EOF Then
    GetData = "n/a"
Else
    GetData = oRecordset(1)
End If

End Function
```

Comment: show us what you have tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to use this code (insert your database path):

```
Public Function getData(whatDate As Date) As Variant

Dim DB As Database
Dim RS As Recordset

Set DB = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("C:\temp\Desktop\Test.mdb")
Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT USD FROM CB_EXCHANGE WHERE RDate = #" & Format(whatDate, "m\/d\/yyyy") & "#", dbOpenDynaset) ' The date format must be like this

If RS.RecordCount > 0 Then
    RS.MoveFirst
    getData = RS!USD ' of course you must enter the correct column name
End If

End Function
```

Comment: No need to convert the database, I just changed the reference "Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library" to "Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library" and it worked very well. Thank you Dorian very much !!!!!!!

Comment: OK, but I have a question. Can the column name be dynamic ?, I mean What if I add a variable in `getData(whatDate As Date, ColName as variant)`, Will this `getData = RS!ColName` work now ?

Comment: Better use `ColName as String`. You have to make two changes. Make the query dynamic `Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT " & ColName & " FROM CB_EXCHANGE WHERE Date = #" & Format(Date, "m\/d\/yyyy") & "#", dbOpenDynaset)` and make the return dynamic via `getData = RS(ColName)`. Your example `getData = RS!ColName` won't work because it would search for a column named "ColName"

Comment: Yes, you are right. That works great. This `getData = RS(ColName)` solved the problem. Thank you very much again !!!)

Comment: You really should edit your answer to omit the "Convert to 2003" statement. It's not only unhelpful, it's misleading.

Answer (score 1):

first you Need to reference the "Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library". I don't know how the menu is named in english VBA Editors. In the german Version it's at "Extras > Verweise..."

Then you Need code like this:

```
Public Function getData(Data as Integer) As Variant
Dim DB As Database
Dim RS As Recordset

Set DB = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("C:\yourPath\yourDatabase.accdb")
Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE Data = " & Data, dbOpenDynaset)

If RS.RecordCount > 0 Then
    RS.MoveFirst
    getData = RS!Date
End If

End Function
```

edit: Sorry, i didn't see you need it in the opposite direction (input a date and get the data) so the function has to be like this:

```
Public Function getData(whatDate as Date) As Variant
Dim DB As Database
Dim RS As Recordset

Set DB = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("C:\yourPath\yourDatabase.accdb")
Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT Data FROM CB_EXCHANGE WHERE Date = #" & Format(Date, "m\/d\/yyyy") & "#", dbOpenDynaset)

If RS.RecordCount > 0 Then
    RS.MoveFirst
    getData = RS!Data
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer . but it gives an error.  
do you mean `SELECT column FROM table`, and if my "Data" is a date, should I write it as `getData(Data as Date)` ?

Comment: Hi, i've updated my answer. Didn't get it right. Yes i've meant `SELECT column FROM table WHERE Date = #7/7/2015#`. Getting the correct date format for the query is a bit tricky, but it should work as in the second function.

Comment: I tried, but it returns #VALUE!, have you tried it ? )

Comment: i tried it now and it works. But there is really a little mistake i made. You need to replace `Format(Date, "m\/d\/yyyy")` by `Format(whatDate, "m\/d\/yyyy")` otherwise it always returns the data for the current day.

Comment: if it doesn't work for you, then try to solve the problem in the immediate window. For example type `?getData("01.06.2015")`. That should either return your data or show a better error message.

Comment: Dear friend, here are my [files](http://www.mediafire.com/download/am1grrnw1ly8t5b/Desktop.rar). please, tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I tried to start it using button and it gave me en ERROR: 
`Error 3343: Unrecognized database format `

Comment: Hi, i tried it with the database and excel you provided. You've found the first error by yourself. I don't know why but it doesn't recognize the database format, so i converted the database to an Access 2003 database. And you've made two mistakes. I can't insert the correct code here, so you get another answer.